# int32 to float32 conversion using xarray : files sizes are bigger

Tags: types, type-conversion, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am working on a nc file conversion (NETCDF4_CLASSIC files), bringing many modifications. In my code, I am trying to add a feature, in order to convert variables values from int32 to float32. The problem is that the output files sizes are different whether or not this feature is enabled or not:

```
# converting values from 'int32' to 'float32' dtype
for var_name in new_nc_file.data_vars:
    if 'add_offset' in new_nc_file.variables[var_name].attrs:
        print(var_name)
        var = new_nc_file[var_name]
        # Apply the scaling and offset to convert the values from int to float
        var.values = (var.values * var.scale_factor + var.add_offset).astype('float32')

comp = {'zlib':True, 'complevel':9}
encoding_comp = {var: comp for var in new_nc_file.variables} # all variables including coordinates

# export following the encoding rules, in NCDF4 classic format
new_nc_file.to_netcdf(output_path, encoding=encoding, format = 'NETCDF4_CLASSIC')
```

With this feature disabled, my output file size is 4120 KB.
With this feature enabled, my output file size is 5816 KB.

Do you know where could it come from ?

Comment: Please show us everything you have done, not just part of it. Did you output a zipped Netcdf file? If not that could explain the difference. Also please avoid including confusing comments in code samples

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I have updated the code. I am using zlib compression.